# Debian fresh install booting to grub prompt

Tags: debian, grub

What would cause a fresh install of Debian 9.5 to boot directly to the grub2 command line instead of the grub menu?  Typing 'exit' at the prompt will take me into the menu where I can boot the system without issue. But for some reason, the default behavior is to boot to the grub command line.

I don't see any option that I can set in /etc/default/grub to override this behavior.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Installed grub2 to two harddrives ie. sda and sdb. Booting sda to empty grub menu, after exiting grub booting from sdb which actually works... = Change boot sequence in bios.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  It's a single disk.  I chose not to partition during the install so /boot is part of the root partition.  There was no option during the install (that I saw anyway) to configure grub, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install grub again from commandline as root.

I assume your devid is `/dev/sda` but it could be different.

Check `fdisk -l` and/or `parted -l` first. Make sure not to grub-install to a partition like `/dev/sda1`.

Example:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Comment: That's actually the first thing I tried after booting back into the OS.  Since my disk is an NVME SSD, the device is recognized as /dev/nvme0n1.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned the disk in question is a NVMe SSD. That makes it likely that the system is booting in UEFI style - and if the ESP partition was not fully wiped in the OS installation, there might be a previous bootloader remaining on the ESP.

With an UEFI system, you can use `efibootmgr -v` to view the firmware boot settings: the `BootCurrent` line will identify the boot setting that was most recently used to boot the system, and so you can use other options of the `efibootmgr` command to delete any boot settings left over from previous OS installations.

For the sake of completeness, you should also look into `/boot/efi/` directory: there should be one sub-directory for each installed OS, Linux distribution or bootloader. If there are remnants from previous installations, you can just delete them as they are regular files.

This kind of problem is unlikely to occur on systems using traditional BIOS boot process unless you have multiple disks, as only one bootloader at a time can occupy the Master Boot Record of a disk.

But if you use MBR partitioning on a modern system that is configured to allow both native UEFI and legacy BIOS-style boot processes, and the boot priority is set to attempt the legacy process first, there might be a remnant of a BIOS-style GRUB still embedded in the MBR and the empty space between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition, which would give you the GRUB prompt because the actual GRUB configuration file it used to use is long gone. When you exit that, the firmware realizes the legacy BIOS-style boot attempt failed, and will try again in UEFI style, and now will find the current bootloader. If that is the problem, the simplest fix might be to enter the BIOS settings and set the boot process as "UEFI only".

Just be careful that you don't also enable Secure Boot, as Debian 9.x does not have Secure Boot support as standard.